# What is the relationship (similarity and differences) between /proc/devices and /dev entries in Linux?

Tags: linux, drivers, sysfs, procfs

When we register a driver, the *"name"* parameter shows up in `/proc/devices`, yet we can write to the devices using the entry in /dev corresponding to the device. What are the core ideas behind /proc and /dev entries? Moving further, is sysfs supposed to be a replacement for procfs? How does it differ from procfs?

Comment: [procfs vs sysfs](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4884/what-is-the-difference-between-procfs-and-sysfs)

Answer (score 7):

`/proc/devices` - List of device drivers configured into the currently running kernel (block and character)

- [/proc/devices](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Reference_Guide/s2-proc-devices.html)

`/dev` - This directory contains the special device files for all the devices

- [/dev](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/dev-fs.html)

> Difference between [procfs vs sysfs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4884/what-is-the-difference-between-procfs-and-sysfs)