# Is sysfs a strict subset of procfs?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, proc, sysfs

Is the information that the Linux kernel provides to the user via [`sysfs`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysfs) a [strict subset](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Subset&oldid=713023920#Definitions) of the information that the Linux kernel provides to the user via [`procfs`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs)?

If not, then which information is provided via `sysfs` that is not provided via `procfs`?

Comment: It pretty clearly isn't; e.g. `/sys/power/state` has no equivalent under `/proc`. Don't know what the rule is for what stuff goes where.

Comment: @TomHunt, thanks :) *"e.g. `/sys/power/state` has no equivalent under `/proc`"*. You're probably right. `procfs` is sufficiently arcane to me that I'm not currently confident drawing that sort of conclusion myself. So, it might be pretty clear to you, but not to me. And therefore maybe not so clear to other people at a similar level of understanding to me. Hence the value in posting the question here - the answers might help me and them alike :)

Comment: I'm going to be somewhat nasty here and point out that should you have read the documentation for [proc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt) and [sysfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs.txt), the answer would be obvious. Hence, it'd be best to read the documentation.

Comment: @SamiLaine, thanks. I did already look at that documentation. The answer was still not obvious to me. To accurately answer the question of whether `sysfs` exposes a *strict subset* of the information exposed by `procfs` requires either exhaustive knowledge of `sysfs` & substantial knowledge of `procfs` (the docs aren't exhaustive), or else knowledge of at least one datum in `sysfs` definitely not present in `procfs`. Tom Hunt suggested `/sys/power/state` as a possible example of the latter. Another (true on my system) is `/sys/block/sda/device/model`. I'll expand this info in an answer.

Comment: I see that Gilles has marked my question as a duplicate of [What is the difference between procfs and sysfs?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4884/what-is-the-difference-between-procfs-and-sysfs). That is an error on Gilles's part. Despite its title, neither that other question nor its answers address the existence (or not) of subset relationships obtaining between the information exposed by `procfs` and `sysfs`; mine does.

Comment: Based on reading the other Q, I'm not sure how to address this. It seems to me that sysfs is growing, so do we want to tag this Q with a specific kernel version number so that it's answerable? Also, does /proc have the same driver interfaces that [Tim Bird](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86614/117549) refers to?

Comment: @JeffSchaller, thanks. I appreciate your concern, but I think it's OK to leave the question as it is. Here's why. *"It seems to me that sysfs is growing"*. `sysfs` is [not a subset](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/280896) of `procfs`, so even if `sysfs` does keep growing then it will continue to not be a subset of `procfs`. At least, that's true as long as `procfs` doesn't grow to become a superset of `sysfs`, which currently seems *very* unlikely. And if that latter unlikely eventuality comes to pass, then hopefully someone will update this question with a new answer to say so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not a strict subset. It is not even a subset.

Here is a demonstration, on a desktop PC running a major GNU/Linux distribution without any customisations that should affect the result, that there is at least one datum present in `sysfs` that is not present in `procfs`:

```
$ grep -ir `cat /sys/block/sda/device/model | cut -f1 -d' '` /sys 2>/dev/null
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata3/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/model:SanDisk [...]
Binary file /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata3/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/vpd_pg83 matches

$ grep -ir `cat /sys/block/sda/device/model | cut -f1 -d' '` /proc 2>/dev/null
Binary file /proc/26887/task/26887/cmdline matches
Binary file /proc/26887/cmdline matches
```

This also demonstrates, incidentally, that on that PC at least, the set of all data exposed by `procfs` is not a subset of the data exposed by `sysfs`.

Answer (score 1):

Sysfs is not at all a subset of procfs. They serve different purposes, see the answers to [What is the difference between procfs and sysfs?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4884/64248).

Comment: The fact that two sets serve different purposes does not mean that one is not a subset of the other. E.g. the set of records in the stock database at my local chain grocery store is (in principle!) a strict subset of those present in the stock database at the store's company's headquarters. The local store's database is for the store manager's routine usage, and is not routinely directly accessed by the company's data scientists or central managers. The database at the HQ is for the routine direct use of the latter two groups, and likely not accessible at all by my local store's manager.