# understanding the /sys directory

Tags: directory

I'm not understanding whats inside the /sys directory.

Is it just a more organized version of /dev? Chatgpt is telling me that:

> The /sys directory in Linux is a virtual filesystem (sysfs) that provides an interface to access and interact with the system's hardware devices and their attributes.

But my first cd into the directory shows the kernel which is most definitely not hardware and after further exploration its just a load of symbolic links pointing to the /dev directory.

If it contains config files, why wouldn't they belong in /etc along with all system configurations? And interface for accessing hardware devices  can be found at /dev and /media if im not mistaken.

Can someone explain what this directory is for? And correct me if need be?

Comment: See also [What is the difference between procfs and sysfs?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4884/86440)

Comment: ChatGPT is not a good source of technical info. From `man hier`: `/sys   This is a mount point for the sysfs filesystem, which provides information about the kernel like /proc, but better structured, following the formalism of kobject infrastructure.`.